# How to click not interactable dropdown with selenium and python and select one option?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I have this dropdown list with id "drp_autogen0". I want to click the dropdown, to see the dropdown options. When I try to click it with Python and Selenium, I get this error: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
I have attached the printscreen of what the dropdown looks like. I want to be able to select "Last month" from the list, but I haven't managed to go that far, because the dropdown is not being clicked.
https://snipboard.io/xDM1Un.jpg

The code for the dropdown click is here:

```
html_list = driver.find_element_by_id("drp_autogen0")
html_list.click()
```

The web code for dropdown button is :

```
<button type="button" class="comiseo-daterangepicker-triggerbutton ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget comiseo-daterangepicker-bottom" id="drp_autogen0">22 Nov 2019<span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span><span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></button>
```

The web code for Last month is:

```
<div id="ui-id-5" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Last month</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check DOM is not changing during run time if not then there are two ways to solve this exception:

**1. Implicitly Wait**

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitly Wait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

**2. WebDriver Wait:**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("<Element path>")));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `ElementNotInteractable` error message, you can try to workaround that using Javascript click:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# first, wait for the button to exist
html_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "drp_autogen0")))

# now click with Javascript
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", html_list)

# now, click last month -- wait for it to exist first!
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Last month']"))).click()
```

This code sample invokes `WebDriverWait` on your desired elements, to ensure they have fully loaded on the page before clicking them.

Then, we use Javascript to click the first `button` element, to work around the `ElementNotInteractable` exception. Once the dropdown is expanded, we wait for the `Last Month` option to exist before attempting to click it.

Even if it seems like the button / dropdown options are appearing on the page instantly, Selenium / Python do move quickly through the DOM, so it's possible that `driver` is trying to click something which does not yet exist. The `WebDriverWait` statements just ensure the element exists on the page before trying to click.